# Unable to browse PHP website hosted in CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, web, centos

We have hosted our PHP website in CentOS OS running on a Codero Server in a datacenter. This site was working fine till last week. But suddenly it stopped working from yesterday. We tried to browse the site on browser. It is throwing "Can't connect to server". We are able to ping this server from command line. That means server is reachable.

We tried to browse with domain name and ip address, both throw same error. Not sure where is the problem. I tried to check httpd.conf, host file, log files etc. But no luck.

Can someone let me know what all things we need to check to resolve this problem. As I'm new to web technology, it is very hard for me to identify the problem. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the webserver demon still running? Seems apache (or nginx or whatever you use) is crashed, so if no webserver is listening on port 80 your browser cannot retrieve a website. It's also good to have a look at all relevant logfiles, syslog, apache.log, apache-error.log etc... Normally they are located in /var/log, see also  https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-logfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the firewall for the web server?

in terminal type

```
system-config-securitylevel 

Go to customize and check www
```

check for more info > 
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=31156